# Xcode 5 - Paste in place/master page/header?

Tags: ios, xcode, header, paste

Is there anyway to "paste in place" in Xcode 5? I've been trying to copy a label and paste it in place as a header on all my pages. Sounds simple but I can't find a simple solution. The "paste & preserve formatting" is greyed out every time I try to use it. Is there something like a master page in Xcode where I can just setup a header?

Comment: Nvm. I was over-complicating it--copying & pasting the entire page with just the header does the job.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the subviews you would copy.
2. Menu/Editor/Embed In > View
3. Cut/Copy/Past the view in another view or another Xib
4. Select the view
5. Menu/Editor/UnEmbed

Done :)